# Laravel -- Why the `::class` Constant

Tags: php, class, laravel, constants

In Laravel 5.1, the kernel for the CLI class looks something like this

```
#File: app/Console/Kernel.php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    //...    
    protected $commands = [
        \App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class,
    ];
    //...
}
```

Is the change to using the predefined/magic constant `::class`

```
\App\Console\Commands\Inspire::class
```

functionally different than simply using the class name?

```
\App\Console\Commands\Inspire
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, using `::class` on a class returns the fully qualified class name, so it's the same thing as writing `'App\Console\Commands\Inspire'` (in quotes, since it's a string). The `class` keyword is new to PHP 5.5.

It looks silly in this example, but it can be useful in e.g. testing or in defining relations. For instance, if I have an `Article` class and an `ArticleComment` class, I might end up doing

```
use Some\Long\Namespace\ArticleComment;

class Article extends Model {

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ArticleComment::class);
    }

}
```

Reference: [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class).

Comment: Derp, thanks!  I forgot the old way included surrounding the class names with strings (as PHP doesn't tokenize class names standing around by themselves).

Answer (score 6):

For executing the code it doesn't make a difference, but the `::class` constant is most useful with development tools. If you use the class name you have to write it as string `'\App\Console\Commands\Inspire'` - that means:

1. No IDE auto completion
2. No suport of automatic refactoring ("rename class")
3. No namespace resolving
4. No way to automatically detect usages (IDE) or dependencies (pDepend)

**Side note:** Before PHP 5.5 came out, I used to define a constant `__CLASS` in most of my own classes for exactly this purpose:

```
class X {
    const __CLASS = __CLASS__;
}
```